# Why if I add the id attribute to span inside bootstrap navbar the JSP/Tiles exceptions aren't shown?

Tags: spring, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, spring-mvc, tiles

I found a weird problem in my project. I'm using `Spring MVC`, `Tiles`, `JSPX` and `Boostrap`.

I have a navbar in my header page, then I added a span to show a badge like https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#badges.

Till here nothing strange. But If I add an `id` on `span` tag and there is an error inside the html code, I can't see any log or exception.

Here the code

```
 <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="fa fa-male"><jsp:text/></span>
      <span class="badge badgeNavbar" id="badgesContrattiDaApprovare">
        <jsp:text/>
      </span> ${clienti} 
      <span class="caret"><jsp:text/></span>
   </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
               ...  
    </ul>
```

Instead If I remove  `id="badgesContrattiDaApprovare"` I can see the exceptions.

Are there any conflicts between `span` and `id`?

SO: **Why if I add the id attribute to the span inside bootstrap navbar the JSP/Tiles exceptions aren't shown inside the rendered view?**

For example here if an exception occurs without the id attribute:

[image]

Instead, if I add the id attribute is like the rendering is stopped, and I see only a blank page. The generated/rendered html code is incomplete.

Comment: I'm a little confused here; you keep emphasizing a potential `<span>` conflict with the ID you reference, when that ID is clearly inside a `<div>`

Comment: @RobertC ops...excuse me, I try to rewrite span with div to see if run. I correct it.